# Google fire stor,e Debug run time Class Path

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, frontend, runtime

i was building sample android porject with google firestore . I added the some dependency for google firestore . Program showed me like this error when i run the program

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration '**:app:debugRuntimeClasspath**'.
```

here is the my project level gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version="1.3.72"
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        def nav_version="2.3.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }

    allprojects{
        repositories{
            google()
        }
    }

}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and module level gradle file is here

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.halil.food_share"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

and i changed to gradle settings file for some reason , here is the gradle.setting file

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "food_share"
include ':app'
```

What can ı do solve this problem in run time ?

Answer (score 0):

build gradle

```
android{
...
compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, it happened when I made this shape

Comment: some eror is following be abi :)